# Importing lists from another file

Tags: python, file, list, import

Currently I am programming something that uses lists. These lists are quite large and I was wondering if I can put them in a separate python file. Then import them.

For example

```
List1 = []
List1.append("Blah")
List1.append("Blah1")
List1.append("Blah2")
List1.append("Blah3")
```

I'd like to have that list in a separate file, then import it so I can use List1 in my main file.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stick another python file in the same directory and then you can import it.

so you would have two files:

settings.py:

```
List1 = []
List1.append("Blah")
List1.append("Blah1")
List1.append("Blah2")
List1.append("Blah3")
```

main.py:

```
import settings
print settings.List1
```

Note that syntactically you could also do this:

```
from settings import List1
print List1
```

but it is usually not recommended to do this...

Comment: and if you don't want to worry about prefixing with the file name, use

    `from settins import *`

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked like a charm. Can't vote it up till 15 rep sadly but thanks!